# Why is it not an error to compare a list to an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In the following example, `print` statement is evaluated with the output "test".

```py
x = [3]
if x != 3:
    print("test")
```

But I don't understand how this works. Is the value `x` assigned to the address of the list `[3]` and therefore `x != 3` evaluates to `True`? Because my intuition says that I should get an `Error` here since you can't compare a `list` to an `int`.

Comment: you can't with < or > but with "!=" or "==" it works. Not the same type => not equal

Comment: You can compare lists and ints for identity, but not value. This statement `3 != [3]` is true, because they're different types.

Comment: note that different types can compare OK, example booleans & integers (because boolean is a specialized integer).

Comment: @Jean e.g. `False == 0 == 0.0`

Comment: oh, right. Because equality operator has been redefined in that case. my answer is not exact.

Answer (score 2):

The Python documentation on [**Comparisons**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) states in part:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal. The `==` operator is always defined but for some object types (for example, class objects) is equivalent to [**is**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is). The `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` operators are only defined where they make sense; for example, they raise a `TypeError` exception when one of the arguments is a complex number.

Hence, Python will let you use `==` and `!=` between any two types, but in the case of comparing a `list` to an integer, they will never compare equal.

Comment: "Objects of different types never compare equal", true but subject to interpretation. `collections.defaultdict` and `dict` can compare equal because one inherits from the other, but they're different types all right. That's not a critic of your answer, but rather of the documentation.

Comment: _The == operator is always defined but for some object types (for example, class objects) is equivalent to is_: unless redefined using `__eq__` and `__ne__`